# Has the MIT license been "Battle tested" in court?

Tags: mit, law, history

The GPL has been pertinent to several [court cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Legal_status).
We know it is strong because it has been "battle-tested".

Can the same be said to be true for the MIT license?

Comment: GPL is a copy left license and it has stricter license conditions than the MIT. Fulfilling the MIT License is easy and therefore I assume most of the people succeed in doing it. You can't go against all the projects that don't fulfil the license conditions, but larger fish are easier to target.

Comment: To add, I've got to say I can't imagine a way for the MIT license to really be "battle-tested." It really only includes a warranty/liability clause, and an attribution clause. I feel like it's also one of those "i-don't-care" licenses - if people want to just let anyone use it for anything, they'll go with MIT. As long as you include the license file, nothing can happen. As for the warranty/liability clause, statutory law in many jurisdictions doesn't place any warranty on software (with exceptions - they need to determine if it's a "good"), so the clause (in theory) just reinforces local law.

Answer (score 6):

There are no court cases I ever heard of, as of this date, involving the MIT license. I am not sure there is anything on BSD either (short of the Berkeley vs. AT&T feud over Unix, last century, maybe). This BSD issue [came](http://www.weeklystandard.com/obamacare-website-violates-licensing-agreement-for-copyrighted-software/article/763666) out close but never went to court. In fact things rarely end up in courts with FLOSS licensing and are mostly resolved amicably, as they should be.